# Promise from check login method is not returning the promise to canActivate()

Tags: angular, promise, angular6, guard, canactivate

I have the following login method:

```
login(username, password)
  {
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    // headerOptions.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // headerOptions.append('Access-Control-Request-Headers', '*');
    // headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // headerOptions.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');


    this.credentials = {user: username, pass: password};
    const httpParams = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', username)
      .set('password', password);


    //console.log("hi "+ this.credentials);
    return this.http.post('http://dev.local/scripts/login.php', httpParams,  {
      headers: headerOptions,
    })
}
```

And when a user is successfully logged in, a JWT array is returned into local storage, so we can check the role, and if it's still logged.

There is a component where only admins has the right to access it, so when a user click on the route:

```
{
    path: 'forgot',
    component: ForgotPasswordComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
},
```

An authGuard will run using the `canActivate()` guard.

```
canActivate(_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
              _state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
  {
    if(this.authApi.checkIsLogin())
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Now to check the `checkIsLogin()`, the following script a executed to return a promise:

```
checkLoggedInAdmin()
  {
    //Get the JWT token from local storage
    let jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    let httpParams = new HttpParams().set('jwt', jwt);
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    const promise = new Promise(
      (resolve, reject)=>{
        if(jwt!="" || jwt!=null || jwt!=undefined)
        {
          this.http.post('http://dev.local/scripts/checkLoginAdmin.php', httpParams, {
            headers: headerOptions
          }).subscribe(
            (data)=>{
              if(data==true)
              {
                this.loggedIn=true;
              }
              else{
                this.loggedIn = false;
              }
            }
          )
        }
        else
        {
         this.loggedIn=false;
        }

        resolve(this.loggedIn),
        reject(this.loggedIn)
      }
    )
}
```

Where `loggedIn` is defined as boolean on top of the class.

And here is the function `checkIsLogin()`:

```
checkIsLogin(){
    return this.loggedIn
}
```

When a user logged in, a jwt is returned, with all necessary details. But if it's an admin, and when clicking on the desired route, nothing happened, and no code is executed, with no errors at the console.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'return false;' rather than 'false;' in the canActivate() ?

Comment: You are missing 'return' in CanActivate(). Nothing is returned from checkLoggedInAdmin().

Comment: Fixed it but still nothing happened on click